# delete row for UITableView in PageViewController

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a requirement to delete rows by swiping to left. Here's the challenge: `UITableView` is present in `PageViewController`. And when I swipe row, the `pageViewController` slides also. Right now I have disabled the scroll of `PageViewController`. But I need to scroll for paging. Please suggest any solution

```
for (UIScrollView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

        view.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this library

[MKSlidingTableViewCell](https://github.com/WinterKirk/MKSlidingTableViewCell)

This library allows user to swipe cell in UITableView for deleting in Page View Controller.

Hope it helps.